# How can i add a custom curved shape inside a sidebar using CSS?

Tags: css, css-shapes

```css
body{
    font-family: roboto;

}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.sidebar{
    
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    width: 314px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #002438;
    box-shadow: hsl(0, 0%, 60%) 7px 2px 15px;
    
    
}
.sidebar header{
    
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: -7%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #002438;
    font-weight: 1000;
    line-height: 30px;
    
    background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 255, 90%);

    border-bottom-left-radius: 200px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 200px;
    
}
.sidebar ul a{

    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
.sidelist :hover{
    color: rgb(24, 234, 253);

}
.sidelist{
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.sidebar header span{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lead Manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <header>LEAD <br> <span>MANAGER</span></header>
                
                
            <ul class="sidelist">
                <li><a href="#">DASHBOARD</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CUSTOMER</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">LEADS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">REPORTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PROFILE</a></li>
            </ul>
            
                
        </div>
        <div class="maskbg"></div>
        <div class="shapemask"></div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This is the shape i want to create inside the sidebar

[image: Curved sidebar shape CSS]

The sidebar is inside a wrapper. I created a simple div also inside the wrapper, but when I give height , width and color to the custom shape, it doesn't show up. The side bar is fixed to the left. I tried looking it up the internet and saw clipping mask mentioned. I put side bar inside a wrapper to see if i can flex it, so that the right side of the side bar is another div which can be used as container for everything else in that page. that is also not working since it doesnt show any error for html and css.

Please note that shapemask and maskbg class is added because i tried to do clipping mask, but in the end I cant even see the simple shape formed out of the div.

Comment: Hi, provide some code. Best of all edit your post to insert "JavaScritp/HTML/CSS Snippet" (there is a button in the toolbar)

Comment: Hi @Akashp, I would suggest you using a svg, as it is a lot easier to use. And if you want to modify it with css (like colors / position) that would be no problem, as you can do that with inline svg and it's subelements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two radial-gradient can do it:

```css
.box {
  width:250px;
  height:400px;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(100% 150% at top,              #002438 50%,transparent 50.2%),
    radial-gradient(100% 180% at top, #a1abb0 48% ,#7f868b 50%,transparent 50.2%),
    #ced0d2;
  background-size:400% 300px;
  background-position:1% 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```